# Laravel isn't loading resource without artisan

Tags: php, laravel, iis, laravel-5

i'm trying my laravel setup on local by using .

```
php artisan serve
```

Everything is working find and asset() are loading. But when i deploy it on xampp or any shared webhosting it doesn't resolve the asset() function it shows error resource not found 404

this is how i'm loading

```
<link href="{{asset('css/app.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Working fine on artisan but not on any other thing not on xampp nor on shared hosting.

Comment: Where on the XAMPP you deploy it? i.e what's the URL of your website on XAMMP?

Comment: When i try on xampp i set it's port to 8080